# Facebook login process

Tags: facebook

Where can I find information on facebook's various servers and their purposes? I know of authentication servers, but what are the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information we have available to us is from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and it's various sub-pages.  Sometimes http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/ has additional nuggets of information that's not explicitly stated in the other places where it should be.